# Linear Algebra/Matrices Reference Request

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, reference-request, regression-analysis

I am learning multivariate regression, with matrix equations and heavy use of:

- Transposes
- Inverses
- Identity, idempotent matrices

Can anyone refer some books where I can learn the properties of matrix equations. Practice problems would be a great help.

(I looked up some standard books on Linear Algebra - for example, Anton - but the topics are different from what I need. For example, Anton has Vector spaces, subspaces, eigenvectors, which is not really what I need).

Comment: Not really what you need, really? Multilinear regression is nothing but projection of $y$ on the column span of $X$. Just gulp the usual linear algebra course, everything will eventually be useful in statistics. In practice linear regression is done with QR decomposition or SVD. And the eigendecomposition (or the SVD) is necessary for principal component analysis. And there are many other examples. Matrix calculus would also be good to know. Everything you skip today, you will miss later.

Comment: I don't mind learning topics, but I am doing regression as a foundation for econometrics. Learning abstract linear algebra is twice removed from econometrics (and I need only the undergraduate non linear algebra version for now).

Comment: @Starlight I'd highly recommend Gilbert Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra". Strang has a bit of a tendency to be verbose, but his text is comprehensive, application oriented, and mostly grounded in the discussion of matrices rather than transformations over vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

A book on matrices that I recommend is [Matrix Analysis](https://anandinstitute.org/pdf/Roger_A.Horn.%20_Matrix_Analysis_2nd_edition(BookSee.org).pdf) by Horn & Johnson and which you can find at the link I adjoined.

If you need something even more basic to start, [Schaum's outline of matrix operations](https://library.uoh.edu.iq/admin/ebooks/62536-bronson---schaum%27s-outline-of-theory-and-problems-of-matrix-operations.pdf) is maybe more advisable.

Comment: Much more basic than the Schaum's Outline book, and possibly all that the OP needs, is [**A Short Course In Matrix Theory**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Short+Course+in+Matrix+Theory%22+Kleinfeld&filter=0) by Erwin Kleinfeld and Margaret Humm Kleinfeld (1997, vi + 158 pages). This is essentially at a school algebra (i.e. precalculus) level and avoids abstract vector space notions. Easily accessible to a student whose mathematical maturity is at the first semester of elementary calculus level.

Comment: Regarding "avoids abstract vector space notions", the book does discuss linear dependence/independence, rank/dimension, null space, basis & orthogonal basis & diagonalization, projections, etc. but only in the context of ${\mathbb R}^n$ (and usually for low values of $n).$ One section deals with applications to differential equations, another to powers of matrices and applications to the Fibonacci sequence, another to least squares approximations, but other than such very isolated places the book only requires school level algebra and (in a few places) very basic trigonometry.

Comment: The matrix analysis books looks good in general, but overkill for my purposes. Let me look at the other two.

Comment: *Matrix Analysis* is a very good book, but I’m afraid it is a very poor choice for the OP’s purpose.